# BIP39 mnemonic from seed

Tags: node.js, seed, mnemonics

I have a simple guestion for experst in this topic.
How can i get mnemonic from generated seed?

```
const bip39 = require('bip39')
var seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync('weasel father present tomorrow shock hover issue attack dial insect oppose vocal')
var mnemonic = ?.fromSeed(seed)
```

> expected: mnemonic == 'weasel father present tomorrow shock hover issue attack dial insect oppose vocal'

I searched the google for a solution, but did not find it. From this I can assume that this is impossible, but still I decided to make sure of this and hear it from people who are well versed in this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the original mnemonic phrase from a BIP39 seed. The seed is a 128-bit (16-byte) value that is derived from the mnemonic phrase using a deterministic process, but it does not contain any information about the original phrase. The mnemonic phrase is only used to generate the seed, and it is not used in any other part of the process.

If you want to recreate the original mnemonic phrase from a seed, you would need to have a record of the original phrase or access to a tool that can generate mnemonic phrases from seeds. However, such a tool does not exist, and it is not possible to recreate the original mnemonic phrase from a seed.

It is important to keep the mnemonic phrase safe and secure, as it is the only way to recreate the seed and access the funds associated with a BIP39 wallet. If you lose the mnemonic phrase, you will not be able to access your funds.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sounds like func mnemonicToSeedSync is trash. What is it used for?

Comment: @PineappleHaze it's used to generate a seed (private key) from your mnemonic, but not the other way around. As MWO explained it is not possible to convert it back, in the same way as if you generate a hash (MD5, SHA) of your mnemonic you cannot convert hash back to mnemonic.